# When I add date picker then show 'Non-nullable instance field 'selectedDate' must be initialized. ' error

Tags: flutter

When I add date picker then show 'Non-nullable instance field 'selectedDate' must be initialized. ' error
[image]

```
DateTime selectedDate;

  

    void showDatePicker() {
        showCupertinoModalPopup(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext builder) {
              return Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith().size.height * 0.25,
                color: Colors.white,
                child: CupertinoDatePicker(
                  mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
                  onDateTimeChanged: (value) {
                    if (value != null && value != selectedDate)
                      setState(() {
                        selectedDate = value;
                      });
                  },
                  initialDateTime: DateTime.now(),
                  minimumYear: 2019,
                  maximumYear: 2021,
                ),
              );
            });
      }
```

widget
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want init variable `selectedDate` later, use late:

```
late DateTime selectedDate;
```

or if you want to make `selectedDate` can have a null value then initiate it like this:

```
DateTime? selectedDate;
```

"?" after data type mean nullable.

Answer (score 0):

You declared `selectedDate` as non-nullable, which means it can never be null. When you do that you need to give it an initial value. The solution is to make it nullable by adding a `?`

```
DateTime? selectedDate;
```